# Difference between set and object in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Lately, I have started studying set theory from the "Elements of Set Theory" book. I'm just confused with the below sentence about what's the difference between set and object in set theory.

> A set is a collection of things (called its members or elements), the collection being regarded as a single object.

Can I say "a set is an object"?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Yes, you can.

Comment: I would say not to worry about this. I do not know the book, but at an elementary level there is no real definition for "sets" or "object" in this context. You can work with sets without knowing the axioms from ZFC. So you might want to accept at first that these terms are not really defined and work with this intuitive describtion.

Comment: "Object" is not a technical word, it is used to convey an intention: for example, some students think that $\{\mathbb{N}\}$ is an infinite set (and, of course, it's not). They may have decided to think of $\{\mathbb{N}\}$ as "a bag containing a bag containing all the integers" leading them to the incorrect answer; whereas $\{\mathbb{N}\}$ should be just considered as "a bag containing one object called $\mathbb{N}$".
In any case, the way of thinking about things is not a formal topic. Finally, the sentence "A set is a collection of things" is very unuseful... It means "a set is a set".

Comment: The stress is on "*single* object" meaning that the collection has properties on his own that can be different from the properties of the elements of the set.

Comment: @Plop I studied more on your statement and I understood that {N} is not an infinite set rather it's a singleton set (an object of N and N itself is a set of natural numbers) which you had explained in your last comment. And Thanks to everyone for sharing insightful information about the set.

Comment: [Russell's paradox (also known as Russell's antinomy)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russell%27s_paradox) shows precisely you are right to be confused?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **PREFACE** of the book

$\quad$Elements Of Set Theory
$\quad$Author:Herbert B. Enderton

begins with the opening paragraph (emphasis ours),

> This is an introductory undergraduate textbook in set theory. In
> mathematics these days, **essentially everything is a set**. Some
> knowledge of set theory is a necessary part of the background everyone
> needs for further study of mathematics. It is also possible to study
> set theory for its own interest--it is a subject with intriguing
> results about simple objects. This book starts with material that
> nobody can do without. There is no end to what can be learned of set
> theory, but here is a beginning.

In

**CHAPTER 1**
**INTRODUCTION**

the reader is immediately presented with the statement

> A set is a collection of things (called its members or elements), the collection being regarded as a single object.

The takeaway? In the study of modern (serious/formal) mathematics, all objects, structures and 'things' can be specified using the language of set theory.

Answer (score 6):

In this quote, the only mathematical terminology is the word "set". All that's happening in that quote is that the "set" terminology is introduced, and you are provided with a hint at how to think about a mathematical "set" using your own native, human intuition. So yes, you can say that "a set is an object", but this is not a formal mathematical statement, it's just a way of talking or communicating; there is no formal mathematical content to the word "object".

This is not dissimilar with the first two lines of Euclid's Elements (following the [Richard Fitzpatrick translation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08T488522)):

> A point is that of which there is no part. 
> And a line is a length without breadth.

Here, again, all that's happening is that the "point" and "line" terminologies are introduced, with hints at how to think about them intuitively, but there is no formal mathematical content to the words "part" or "length" or "breadth".